# Why use Definitely Typed typescript files for Knockout/jQuery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, typescript, definitelytyped

This might be a dumb question, but can someone tell me if it is 'required' to use definitely typed (.d.ts) versions of external libraries with Typescript?
I have a code base that uses jQuery and Knockout in the conventional way (including script/cdns in html file). Also, I need to update the code base to use Typescript. I would like to know if these is an issue with keeping the jQuery and knockout references intact and still use Typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not *required*.

They are mostly useful for tooling support (e.g. intellisense) and compile time checks, as they describe the API of an external library. If you don't care about that you can forego including them, but you will probably need to tell Typescript about the globals that these libraries expose.

For example:

```
declare var ko, $, jQuery;
ko.applyBindings({}, $(".root-container"))[0];
```

There's more clever ways than these `declare`s, in fact that's *exactly* what `.d.ts` files contain: clever declarations of the library you're using. Have a look [e.g. at the Knockout `.d.ts` file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout/knockout.d.ts) (start at the bottom I'd say), they're not all too complicated.